# jQuery draggable('cancel') causing error: this.helper is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I've got a jQuery draggable() slider that I want to cancel at a certain event, however this causes the error: 'this.helper is null'. The code is simply:

```
$( '#magicalscrollhandle' ).draggable( 'cancel' );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"cancel" isn't actually a valid [method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#methods) on the draggable widget.

The best way I've come across to cancel a drag event is to return `false` from the `drag` event handler.  You could do this based on some condition that you set based on your event occurring:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("cancel")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

So you would apply the class `cancel` to stop the dragging.

Here's a small example in which I set a timer which causes the element to stop being draggable after 5 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/y2yrA/1/

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the problem with this is that I only want to cancel the handler at a certain point, say the user drags it to the end, I want to cancel it then (so that it's detached from the mouse and can be moved) but then allow the user to grab it again (so another onmousedown) and drag it.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, it's been a loooong morning (ha?), I've just see what you did there :D