# Cancel dragging of a sortable item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

An absolutely common sortable case:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
</script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Problem.** Need to cancel dragging of an item on some condition and there is a good advice of  [Andrew Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006271/jquery-draggablecancel-causing-error-this-helper-is-null/5012029#5012029), but that approach is working only for jquery-ui-draggable and fails for sortables:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  start: function() {
    return false; // will still cause `this.helper is null`
  }
});
```

Will be greateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `sort` function callback does the same for sort as drag for draggable ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/7CuMF/)):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    sort: function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("cancel")) {
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470835/jquery-sortable-cancel-event-if-not-valid

Comment: i have also fetch thi error  error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" but your answer is not work proper.. because i have return false then my drag items disable and second time not drag gable

Answer (score 29):

Returning `false` as [fudgey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133279/cancel-dragging-of-a-sortable-item/5133395#5133395) suggests works great for making things dynamically unsortable, but there's also a [`cancel` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) in the sortable config which lets you set up static unsortables as well:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    // this prevents all buttons, form fields, and elemens
    // with the "unsortable" class from being dragged
    cancel: ":input, button, .unsortable"
});
```

Comment: Be aware that any nested sortables below elements which have the cancel CSS class applied to them (e.g. within nested tree views) will also be disabled for sorting even if they do not have that class applied.

Answer (score 28):

Sortable has a "cancel" capability invoked using `sortable('cancel')`.

From the docs: "Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state prior to when the current sort was started." See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel.

Example usage:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    if ("I need to cancel this") {
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `ui.sender` cannot be used here since `sender` is the sortable that the item comes from if moving from one sortable to another (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop). If you want that single sortable use `$(this).sortable('cancel')`

Answer (score 10):

Try [this example](http://codepen.io/mj_azani/pen/npohF)

```
$('#list1').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul'
});    

$('#list2').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    receive: function(ev, ui) {
       if(ui.item.hasClass("number"))
          ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
    }
});
```

Comment: super awesome.. it took half day and at the end of the day answer is here

Comment: Great implementation, based on classname just like I needed.