# Cancel drag before it starts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI sortable and am simply trying to prevent dragging if condition is true. I've come across this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18470982/3758078 but that cancels the drag when drag stops, not before it begins. Other solutions advise to use `return false;` in the `sort:` event but that simply returns an error.

```
    $(elements).sortable({
        start: function() {
           if( true ) {
               //cancel dragging before it begins
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you use the "disable" method to prevent it even starting?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example using the `start` callback.
You can use the `allowdrag` checkbox to enable/disable the dragging functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      start: function(e) {
        if (!$('#allowdrag').is(':checked')) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
    $("#Dropable").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("dropped!");
        },
        tolerance: 'fit'
    });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
#Dropable {
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="allowdrag" /><label for="allowdrag"> Allow drag</label><br />
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div id="Dropable">Droppable area</div>
```

You can change the `if (!$('#allowdrag').is(':checked')) {` part to whatever you want to check in order to enable/disable the drag option.

Comment: I'm using sortable(); this example uses draggable. I used e.preventDefault within start event and got console error.

Comment: @guub it should work exactly the same. Did you add the `e` variable into the `function(e) {.. }` definition?

Comment: @guub did you check it?

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324065

> Could create a DisableDrag(myObject) and a EnableDrag(myObject) function

`myObject.draggable( 'disable' )`

Then

`myObject.draggable( 'enable' )`